# Splitting on multiple delimiters but keep the delimiters on the same string

Tags: java, regex, split

I want help with regular expressions to solve the following problem:

I have a string such as "1£23$456$£$"

when I split on it I want the output in my string array to contain:

```
1£
23$
456$
£
$
```

Anyone have any idea on how best to tackle this problem?  The solution needs to meet these additional requirements:

1. Also split on delimiter characters: `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`
2. Non-delimiter characters are only digits with optional spaces before the delimiters.
3. Any such spaces are part of the value, not delimiters themselves.

Comment: Are the pound sign and dollar sign the only two delimiters which will ever be found in your input strings, or are other delimiters possible? A good regular expression can only be crafted when the limits of the input are known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the more powerful `Matcher` functionality instead of `String.split`.  The below code should work, but has not been optimized:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d*(\\$|£)");

String input = "1£23$456$£$";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    output.add(matcher.group());
}
```

Printing out `output.toString()` generates:

> `[1£, 23$, 456$, £, $]`

---

Updated requirements:

1. Also include delimiter characters: `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`
2. Non-delimiter characters are only digits with optional spaces before the delimiters.
3. Any such spaces are part of the value, not delimiters themselves.

Use the regular expression: `\\d*\\s*[-\\+\\*/\\$£]`

That pattern, with this given input:

> `1£23$456$£$7+89-1011*121314/1 £23 $456 $ £ $7 +89 -1011 * 121314 /`

Will generate this output:

> `[1£, 23$, 456$, £, $, 7+, 89-, 1011*, 121314/, 1 £, 23 $, 456 $,  £,  $, 7 +, 89 -, 1011 *, 121314 /]`

Comment: looks like it has an issue with the regex you are using or more to the point an invalid escape sequence.

Comment: Thanks, so i added + - * / as well which gave me \\d*(\\$|£|-|\\+|\\*|/) but this seems to be wrong, can you confirm if i am making a mistake

Comment: the input can also contain spaces so an input could or normally will be is 9 * 9 / 9 $ £

output should be as above

Comment: @user1383163 Is the space considered a delimiter or part of the numeric value?  While we're at it does the value before the delimiters only consist of digits or other text?

Comment: only digits are in the string, spaces are not considered delimiters but part of the value

Answer (score 2):

Use a look behind, which is non-consuming:

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=\\D)");
```

That's all there is to it. The regex means to split "just after every non-digit", which seems to be exactly your intention.

---

Some test code:

```
String str = "1£23$456$£$";
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=\\D)");
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( parts));
```

Output:

```
[1£, 23$, 456$, £, $]
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^$£]*(\\$|£)").matcher(input);
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `[^$£]*(\$|£)`